# How do I do test automation of RFID Tag reader?

Tags: testing, rfid, ios-ui-automation

We have a mobile app where in the RFID reader reads the RFID tags info and then we process that info in the app. How do I simulate this flow so that I do not have to depend on the RFID reader everytime?